# a grid in tabPanel error

Tags: gwt, datagrid, grid, gxt, tabpanel

I'm using a grid example to show it in my tabPanel.
The problem is that i dont get my data store in my grid and it is empty.
The code i'm using is

```
    package com.google.mdlight.shared;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.Style.HorizontalAlignment;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseModel;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BasePagingLoader;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.ModelData;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.PagingLoadResult;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.PagingLoader;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.PagingModelMemoryProxy;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.store.ListStore;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.ContentPanel;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.LayoutContainer;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.ColumnConfig;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.ColumnData;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.ColumnModel;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.Grid;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.GridCellRenderer;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.layout.FitLayout;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.layout.FlowLayout;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.table.NumberCellRenderer;
import com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.toolbar.PagingToolBar;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.DateTimeFormat;
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.NumberFormat;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

class GridUsers extends LayoutContainer {
  @Override
  protected void onRender(Element parent, int index) {
    super.onRender(parent, index);
    // super.onRender(parent, index);  
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(10));  
         getAriaSupport().setPresentation(true);  
   // setLayout(new FlowLayout(10));

    // add paging support for a local collection of models
    PagingModelMemoryProxy proxy = new PagingModelMemoryProxy(getStocks());

    // loader
    PagingLoader<PagingLoadResult<ModelData>> loader = new BasePagingLoader<PagingLoadResult<ModelData>>(proxy);
    loader.setRemoteSort(true);

    ListStore<Stock> store = new ListStore<Stock>(loader);

    final PagingToolBar toolBar = new PagingToolBar(10);
    toolBar.bind(loader);

    loader.load(0, 10);

    final NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyFormat();
    final NumberFormat number = NumberFormat.getFormat("0.00");
    final NumberCellRenderer<Grid<Stock>> numberRenderer = new NumberCellRenderer<Grid<Stock>>(currency);

    GridCellRenderer<Stock> change = new GridCellRenderer<Stock>() {
      public String render(Stock model, String property, ColumnData config, int rowIndex, int colIndex,
          ListStore<Stock> store, Grid<Stock> grid) {
        double val = (Double) model.get(property);
        String style = val < 0 ? "red" : "green";
        return "<span style='color:" + style + "'>" + number.format(val) + "</span>";
      }
    };

    GridCellRenderer<Stock> gridNumber = new GridCellRenderer<Stock>() {
      public String render(Stock model, String property, ColumnData config, int rowIndex, int colIndex,
          ListStore<Stock> store, Grid<Stock> grid) {
        return numberRenderer.render(null, property, model.get(property));
      }
    };

    List<ColumnConfig> configs = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig>();

    ColumnConfig column = new ColumnConfig();
    column.setId("name");
    column.setHeader("Company");
    column.setWidth(200);
    configs.add(column);

    column = new ColumnConfig();
    column.setId("symbol");
    column.setHeader("Symbol");
    column.setWidth(100);
    configs.add(column);

    column = new ColumnConfig();
    column.setId("last");
    column.setHeader("Last");
    column.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
    column.setWidth(75);
    column.setRenderer(gridNumber);
    configs.add(column);

    column = new ColumnConfig("change", "Change", 100);
    column.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
    column.setRenderer(change);
    configs.add(column);

    column = new ColumnConfig("date", "Last Updated", 100);
    column.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
    //column.setDateTimeFormat(DateTimeFormat.getShortDateFormat());
    configs.add(column);

    ColumnModel cm = new ColumnModel(configs);


    ContentPanel cp = new ContentPanel();
   // cp.setFrame(true);
    cp.setHeading("Local Paging Grid");
    //cp.setIcon(Resources.ICONS.table());
    cp.setButtonAlign(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    cp.setLayout(new FitLayout());
    cp.setBottomComponent(toolBar);
    cp.setSize(600, 200);

    Grid<Stock> grid = new Grid<Stock>(store, cm);
    grid.setBorders(true);
    grid.setAutoExpandColumn("name");

    cp.add(grid);

    add(cp);
  }
  public static List<Stock> getStocks() {
    List<Stock> stocks = new ArrayList<Stock>();

    stocks.add(new Stock("Apple Inc.", "AAPL", 125.64, 123.43));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Cisco Systems, Inc.", "CSCO", 25.84, 26.3));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Google Inc.", "GOOG", 516.2, 512.6));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Intel Corporation", "INTC", 21.36, 21.53));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Level 3 Communications, Inc.", "LVLT", 5.55, 5.54));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Microsoft Corporation", "MSFT", 29.56, 29.72));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Nokia Corporation (ADR)", "NOK", 27.83, 27.93));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Oracle Corporation", "ORCL", 18.73, 18.98));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Starbucks Corporation", "SBUX", 27.33, 27.36));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Yahoo! Inc.", "YHOO", 26.97, 27.29));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Applied Materials, Inc.", "AMAT", 18.4, 18.66));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Comcast Corporation", "CMCSA", 25.9, 26.4));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Sirius Satellite", "SIRI", 2.77, 2.74));

    stocks.add(new Stock("Tellabs, Inc.", "TLAB", 10.64, 10.75));
    stocks.add(new Stock("eBay Inc.", "EBAY", 30.43, 31.21));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Broadcom Corporation", "BRCM", 30.88, 30.48));
    stocks.add(new Stock("CMGI Inc.", "CMGI", 2.14, 2.13));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Amgen, Inc.", "AMGN", 56.22, 57.02));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Limelight Networks", "LLNW", 23, 22.11));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Amazon.com, Inc.", "AMZN", 72.47, 72.23));

    stocks.add(new Stock("E TRADE Financial Corporation", "ETFC", 24.32, 24.58));
    stocks.add(new Stock("AVANIR Pharmaceuticals", "AVNR", 3.7, 3.52));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Gemstar-TV Guide, Inc.", "GMST", 4.41, 4.55));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Akamai Technologies, Inc.", "AKAM", 43.08, 45.32));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Motorola, Inc.", "MOT", 17.74, 17.69));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.", "AMD", 13.77, 13.98));
    stocks.add(new Stock("General Electric Company", "GE", 36.8, 36.91));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Texas Instruments Incorporated", "TXN", 35.02, 35.7));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Qwest Communications", "Q", 9.9, 10.03));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Tyco International Ltd.", "TYC", 33.48, 33.26));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Pfizer Inc.", "PFE", 26.21, 26.19));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Time Warner Inc.", "TWX", 20.3, 20.45));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Sprint Nextel Corporation", "S", 21.85, 21.76));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Bank of America Corporation", "BAC", 49.92, 49.73));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Taiwan Semiconductor", "TSM", 10.4, 10.52));
    stocks.add(new Stock("AT&T Inc.", "T", 39.7, 39.66));
    stocks.add(new Stock("United States Steel Corporation", "X", 115.81, 114.62));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Exxon Mobil Corporation", "XOM", 81.77, 81.86));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Valero Energy Corporation", "VLO", 72.46, 72.6));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Micron Technology, Inc.", "MU", 12.02, 12.27));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Verizon Communications Inc.", "VZ", 42.5, 42.61));
    stocks.add(new Stock("Avaya Inc.", "AV", 16.96, 16.96));
    stocks.add(new Stock("The Home Depot, Inc.", "HD", 37.66, 37.79));

    stocks.add(new Stock("First Data Corporation", "FDC", 32.7, 32.65));
    return stocks;

  }
}

class Stock extends BaseModel {

  public Stock() {
  }

  public Stock(String name, String symbol, double open, double last) {
    set("name", name);
    set("symbol", symbol);
    set("open", open);
    set("last", last);
    set("date", new Date());
    set("change", last - open);
  }

  public Stock(String name, double open, double change, double pctChange, Date date, String industry) {
    set("name", name);
    set("open", open);
    set("change", change);
    set("percentChange", pctChange);
    set("date", date);
    set("industry", industry);
  }

  public String getIndustry() {
    return get("industry");
  }

  public void setIndustry(String industry) {
    set("industry", industry);
  }

  public Date getLastTrans() {
    return (Date) get("date");
  }

  public String getName() {
    return (String) get("name");
  }

  public String getSymbol() {
    return (String) get("symbol");
  }

  public double getOpen() {
    Double open = (Double) get("open");
    return open.doubleValue();
  }

  public double getLast() {
    Double open = (Double) get("last");
    return open.doubleValue();
  }

  public double getChange() {
    return getLast() - getOpen();
  }

  public double getPercentChange() {
    return getChange() / getOpen();
  }

  public String toString() {
    return getName();
  }

}
```

and i insert it to my tabPanel like this

```
final TabItem itemAdmin = new TabItem();  
                   itemAdmin.setId("admin");
                   itemAdmin.setText("Administration ");   
                   //itemAdmin.addText("Administration ici ");  
                   itemAdmin.addStyleName("pad-text"); 
                   itemAdmin.setAutoHeight(true);
                   itemAdmin.setAutoWidth(true);

                   itemAdmin.add(new GridUsers()); //le grid dans le module reporting //le formulaire dans le module administration
```

When i clic on my page i get this error

```
14:12:28.062 [ERROR] [mdlight] Uncaught exception escaped

java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.GridTemplates' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:98)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.GridView.initTemplates(GridView.java:1356)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.GridView.init(GridView.java:1229)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.grid.Grid.onRender(Grid.java:880)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Component.render(Component.java:1023)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Layout.renderComponent(Layout.java:361)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Layout.renderAll(Layout.java:352)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Layout.onLayout(Layout.java:318)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.layout.FitLayout.onLayout(FitLayout.java:58)
    at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Layout.layout(Layout.java:114)
....
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:281)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:531)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Is there someone who faced this problem?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply as it states it looks like your missing an inherited module, More specifically the one that contains `GridTemplates.class` within it as its failing on the create.

Ensure the GXT.jar file is present as well as its dependencies.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hello, thank you for tou response. i tried  GridUsers extends LayoutContainer implements GridTemplates, but i get always the same result. how can i inherit the missing module please. thank you again for your response. Kind regards

Comment: No this is likely the actual jar, if your using eclipse right click on the project and go to properties then navigate to "java build path"- "libraries" and add the required jar files

Answer (score 0):

check [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069746/gxt-ext-gwt-default-grid-widget-implementation-whats-wrong) on stack overflow
and the forum of sencha about the [same issue](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?123936-GWT-2.2.0)

it seems that you have a misfit between the ver of the gxt and the gwt